# Why might Craft CMS performance significantly drop on wamp upgrading from 3.7.54 to 4.4.1?

Tags: performance

I have upgraded our site from Craft 3.7.54 to 4.4.1 on my local wamp server to prep for upgrading our staging environment and I'm noticing a fairly significant speed drop and I can't quite figure why that might be the case.

Here's a comparison between 3.7.54 and 4.4.1

[image: Comparison between 3.7.54 and 4.4.1]

Local server is WAMP 3.2.9 64bit (Don't judge me please, I can be a terrible creature of habbit)

Apache 2.4.46

PHP 8.0.26

MySQL 5.7.31

Installed plugins:
Azure Blob Storage, Redactor, Retour, a custom plugin for handling job listings. I have tried disabling all plugins and see no change.

I reduced the page I'm testing to one use just one element query and it was still slower than  3.7. The simple element query is below.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('markets').with([ ['smallImage', {kind: 'image', withTransforms: [listed] }] ]).level(1).all() %}
```

Any thoughts on what the culprit for the drop in performance locally may be? I have not pushed any of this to staging environments to test as of yet.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Is your Composer autoloader optimized? Try running `composer dump-autoload -o`.

Comment: @BrandonKelly Just tried that and it seems that nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm assuming you updated the PHP version in WAMP as part of this upgrade - did anything else change in WAMP?

Comment: @BradBell I had added PHP 8 a while back for another project. I don't recall any other changes to WAMP at that time. I made the changes to the php.ini to increase memory_limit, max_input_nesting_level and max_input_vars, but that was about it. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose as a next step, I'd push it to another environment to help rule out if it's a WAMP issue or code issue.

Comment: @BradBell Yeah, I think that's my next step. I'm out of town for a few days but will give it a whirl next week and see if I'm experiencing similar slowdowns.